# How to change the body color but not affect the divs?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Recently hit a wall. Have tried the body:not(.wrapper .group) selector but it doesn't change the outer div color.

I can't find another way to change the body color without messing

Here's what I have so far:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #8e44ad;
  color: white;
}

/*body:not(.wrapper .group) {
  background: white;
}*/

.wrapper {
  margin: 50px 20px 50px 20px;
  /* background-color: chartreuse; */
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
    /* background: #8e44ad;
    color: white; */
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.newdiv {
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.group1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.group3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  line-height: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
label:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3em;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 1.4em;
  height: 1.4em;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  z-index: -1;
}

input[type="radio"] + label::before {
  border-radius: 1em;
}

/* Checked */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label,
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  padding-left: 1em;
  color: #8e44ad;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before,
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  background: white;
}

/* Transition */
label,
label::before {
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s all ease;
  -o-transition: 0.25s all ease;
  transition: 0.25s all ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Pure CSS Fancy Checkbox/Radio</h1>

      <h2>Radio Buttons</h2>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="radio" name="rb" id="rb1" />
        <label for="rb1">Check this</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rb" id="rb2" />
        <label for="rb2">... or this...</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rb" id="rb3" />
        <label for="rb3">or maybe this</label>
      </div>

      <h2>Checkbox</h2>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb1" />
        <label for="cb1">Heart disease </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb2" />
        <label for="cb2">Anemia or other blood disease</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb3" />
        <label for="cb3">Severe headaches</label>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1d" />
        <label for="q1d">Neck pain</label> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1e" />
        <label for="q1e">High cholesterol</label>
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1f" />
        <label for="q1f">Stomach disease</label>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1g" />
        <label for="q1g">Stroke</label> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1h" />
        <label for="q1h">Sleep apnea</label> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1i" />
        <label for="q1i">Diabetes</label> <br />
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1j" />
        <label for="q1j">Cancer (past or present) </label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1k" />
        <label for="q1k">Depression</label> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1l" />
        <label for="q1l">High blood pressure</label>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1m" />
        <label for="q1m" class="radio-inline">Thyroid disease</label>
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1n" />
        <label for="q1n">Seizures</label> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1o" />
        <label for="q1o">Back pain</label> <br />
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1p" />
        <label for="q1p">Lung disease</label> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1q" />
        <label for="q1q">Kidney, bladder or prostate disease</label>
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1r" />
        <label for="q1r">Blood clots</label> <br />
      </div>
      <div class="newdiv">
        <div class="group1">
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1j" />
          <label for="q1j">Cancer (past or present) </label><br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1k" />
          <label for="q1k">Depression</label> <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1l" />
          <label for="q1l">High blood pressure</label>
        </div>
        <div class="group1">
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1m" />
          <label for="q1m" class="radio-inline">Thyroid disease</label>
          <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1n" />
          <label for="q1n">Seizures</label> <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1o" />
          <label for="q1o">Back pain</label> <br />
        </div>
        <div class="group3">
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1p" />
          <label for="q1p">Lung disease</label> <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1q" />
          <label for="q1q">Kidney, bladder or prostate disease</label>
          <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1r" />
          <label for="q1r">Blood clots</label> <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is it you want to obtain? Color of the body and color of the wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

By default, all elements that are children of `body` (and most other elements, for that matter) inherit its `background` attribute. Like suggested by o.v., changing the background of the `.wrapper` element will work. See the jsFiddle below.

https://jsfiddle.net/us3fct9w/

Answer (score 0):

The `.wrapper` element has a transparent background by default, so it appears purple.

Try setting a background colour that works with your design.

Answer (score 0):

Move your margin property from .wrapper to body, and change it to padding. Then move your background property from body to .wrapper, and give .wrapper a small margin.

Changes:

```
body{
   /* Remove background: #8e44ad;*/
   /* Add padding: 50px 20px 50px 20px;*/
}

.wrapper {
   /* Remove margin: 50px 20px 50px 20px; */
   /* Add background: #8e44ad; */
   /* Add padding: 20px; */
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px 20px 50px 20px;
}

body:not(.wrapper.group) {
 /* background: white;*/
}

.wrapper {
  background: #8e44ad;
  padding: 20px;

/* background-color: chartreuse; */
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
    /* background: #8e44ad;
    color: white; */
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.newdiv {
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.group1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.group3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  line-height: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
label:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3em;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 1.4em;
  height: 1.4em;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  z-index: -1;
}

input[type="radio"] + label::before {
  border-radius: 1em;
}

/* Checked */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label,
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  padding-left: 1em;
  color: #8e44ad;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before,
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  background: white;
}

/* Transition */
label,
label::before {
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s all ease;
  -o-transition: 0.25s all ease;
  transition: 0.25s all ease;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Pure CSS Fancy Checkbox/Radio</h1>

      <h2>Radio Buttons</h2>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="radio" name="rb" id="rb1" />
        <label for="rb1">Check this</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rb" id="rb2" />
        <label for="rb2">... or this...</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rb" id="rb3" />
        <label for="rb3">or maybe this</label>
      </div>

      <h2>Checkbox</h2>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb1" />
        <label for="cb1">Heart disease </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb2" />
        <label for="cb2">Anemia or other blood disease</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb3" />
        <label for="cb3">Severe headaches</label>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1d" />
        <label for="q1d">Neck pain</label> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1e" />
        <label for="q1e">High cholesterol</label>
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1f" />
        <label for="q1f">Stomach disease</label>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1g" />
        <label for="q1g">Stroke</label> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1h" />
        <label for="q1h">Sleep apnea</label> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1i" />
        <label for="q1i">Diabetes</label> <br />
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1j" />
        <label for="q1j">Cancer (past or present) </label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1k" />
        <label for="q1k">Depression</label> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1l" />
        <label for="q1l">High blood pressure</label>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1m" />
        <label for="q1m" class="radio-inline">Thyroid disease</label>
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1n" />
        <label for="q1n">Seizures</label> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1o" />
        <label for="q1o">Back pain</label> <br />
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1p" />
        <label for="q1p">Lung disease</label> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1q" />
        <label for="q1q">Kidney, bladder or prostate disease</label>
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1r" />
        <label for="q1r">Blood clots</label> <br />
      </div>
      <div class="newdiv">
        <div class="group1">
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1j" />
          <label for="q1j">Cancer (past or present) </label><br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1k" />
          <label for="q1k">Depression</label> <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1l" />
          <label for="q1l">High blood pressure</label>
        </div>
        <div class="group1">
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1m" />
          <label for="q1m" class="radio-inline">Thyroid disease</label>
          <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1n" />
          <label for="q1n">Seizures</label> <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1o" />
          <label for="q1o">Back pain</label> <br />
        </div>
        <div class="group3">
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1p" />
          <label for="q1p">Lung disease</label> <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1q" />
          <label for="q1q">Kidney, bladder or prostate disease</label>
          <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1r" />
          <label for="q1r">Blood clots</label> <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Tried it before, the problem is the boxes are inexistent, and text gets the same color as bg when clicked. Anyway ty for the help!

Comment: @suigetsuh17 I wasn't sure exactly what you were going for, in terms of the different layers and what colors you wanted them. If you're able to update your answer with descriptions, or even an image, I'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your have a problem because of your z-index.

In this case you could set your label to `z-index: 2;`

Here is a screenshot, since you don't seem to get the same result as I do.
[image]

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background:white;
  color: white;
}


.wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #8e44ad;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.newdiv {
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.group1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.group3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  line-height: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
}

label:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3em;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 1.4em;
  height: 1.4em;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  z-index: -1;
}

input[type="radio"] + label::before {
  border-radius: 1em;
}

/* Checked */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label,
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  padding-left: 1em;
  color: #8e44ad;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before,
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  background: white;
}

/* Transition */
label,
label::before {
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s all ease;
  -o-transition: 0.25s all ease;
  transition: 0.25s all ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Pure CSS Fancy Checkbox/Radio</h1>

      <h2>Radio Buttons</h2>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="radio" name="rb" id="rb1" />
        <label for="rb1">Check this</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rb" id="rb2" />
        <label for="rb2">... or this...</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rb" id="rb3" />
        <label for="rb3">or maybe this</label>
      </div>

      <h2>Checkbox</h2>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb1" />
        <label for="cb1">Heart disease </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb2" />
        <label for="cb2">Anemia or other blood disease</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb3" />
        <label for="cb3">Severe headaches</label>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1d" />
        <label for="q1d">Neck pain</label> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1e" />
        <label for="q1e">High cholesterol</label>
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1f" />
        <label for="q1f">Stomach disease</label>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1g" />
        <label for="q1g">Stroke</label> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1h" />
        <label for="q1h">Sleep apnea</label> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1i" />
        <label for="q1i">Diabetes</label> <br />
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1j" />
        <label for="q1j">Cancer (past or present) </label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1k" />
        <label for="q1k">Depression</label> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1l" />
        <label for="q1l">High blood pressure</label>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1m" />
        <label for="q1m" class="radio-inline">Thyroid disease</label>
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1n" />
        <label for="q1n">Seizures</label> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1o" />
        <label for="q1o">Back pain</label> <br />
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1p" />
        <label for="q1p">Lung disease</label> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1q" />
        <label for="q1q">Kidney, bladder or prostate disease</label>
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1r" />
        <label for="q1r">Blood clots</label> <br />
      </div>
      <div class="newdiv">
        <div class="group1">
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1j" />
          <label for="q1j">Cancer (past or present) </label><br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1k" />
          <label for="q1k">Depression</label> <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1l" />
          <label for="q1l">High blood pressure</label>
        </div>
        <div class="group1">
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1m" />
          <label for="q1m" class="radio-inline">Thyroid disease</label>
          <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1n" />
          <label for="q1n">Seizures</label> <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1o" />
          <label for="q1o">Back pain</label> <br />
        </div>
        <div class="group3">
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1p" />
          <label for="q1p">Lung disease</label> <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1q" />
          <label for="q1q">Kidney, bladder or prostate disease</label>
          <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1r" />
          <label for="q1r">Blood clots</label> <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your solution has the same result as the commenter below. When element is clicked, it gets the bg color(purple) so it disappears. Anyway ty for the suggestion!

Comment: And now? I added a z-index rule on label instead of wrapper. It works for me, but I don't know exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As o.v & Jason Steinhauser mentioned above, changing the body would affect the elements below in hierarchy, so I changed the design approach.

Thanks for the help guys, I really needed this kind of feedback, especially when I code for some long hours and my mind is clouded!

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #fff;
  color: #15c39a;
  font-family: "Gotham Light", "Futura Bold Italic";
  font-weight: 100;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham Light";
  src: url("Fonts/Gotham/Gotham-Light.otf");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 50px 20px 50px 20px;
  padding: 20px 0px 10px 20px;
  border: 2px solid #15c39a;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.newdiv {
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.group1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.group3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  line-height: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
label:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3em;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 1.4em;
  height: 1.4em;
  border: 2px solid #15c39a;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  z-index: -1;
}

input[type="radio"] + label::before {
  border-radius: 1em;
}

/* Checked */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label,
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  padding-left: 1em;
  color: #8e44ad;
  color: #fff;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before,
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  background: #15c39a;
}

/* Transition */
label,
label::before {
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s all ease;
  -o-transition: 0.25s all ease;
  transition: 0.25s all ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Pure CSS Fancy Checkbox/Radio</h1>

        <h2>Radio Buttons</h2>
        <div class="group">
          <input type="radio" name="rb" id="rb1" />
          <label for="rb1">Check this</label>
          <input type="radio" name="rb" id="rb2" />
          <label for="rb2">... or this...</label>
          <input type="radio" name="rb" id="rb3" />
          <label for="rb3">or maybe this</label>
        </div>

        <h2>Checkbox</h2>
        <div class="group">
          <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb1" />
          <label for="cb1">Heart disease </label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb2" />
          <label for="cb2">Anemia or other blood disease</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb3" />
          <label for="cb3">Severe headaches</label>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1d" />
          <label for="q1d">Neck pain</label> <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1e" />
          <label for="q1e">High cholesterol</label>
          <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1f" />
          <label for="q1f">Stomach disease</label>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1g" />
          <label for="q1g">Stroke</label> <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1h" />
          <label for="q1h">Sleep apnea</label> <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1i" />
          <label for="q1i">Diabetes</label> <br />
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1j" />
          <label for="q1j">Cancer (past or present) </label><br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1k" />
          <label for="q1k">Depression</label> <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1l" />
          <label for="q1l">High blood pressure</label>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1m" />
          <label for="q1m" class="radio-inline">Thyroid disease</label>
          <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1n" />
          <label for="q1n">Seizures</label> <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1o" />
          <label for="q1o">Back pain</label> <br />
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1p" />
          <label for="q1p">Lung disease</label> <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1q" />
          <label for="q1q">Kidney, bladder or prostate disease</label>
          <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1r" />
          <label for="q1r">Blood clots</label> <br />
        </div>
        <div class="newdiv">
          <div class="group1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1j" />
            <label for="q1j">Cancer (past or present) </label><br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1k" />
            <label for="q1k">Depression</label> <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1l" />
            <label for="q1l">High blood pressure</label>
          </div>
          <div class="group1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1m" />
            <label for="q1m" class="radio-inline">Thyroid disease</label>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1n" />
            <label for="q1n">Seizures</label> <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1o" />
            <label for="q1o">Back pain</label> <br />
          </div>
          <div class="group3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1p" />
            <label for="q1p">Lung disease</label> <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1q" />
            <label for="q1q">Kidney, bladder or prostate disease</label>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="a" id="q1r" />
            <label for="q1r">Blood clots</label> <br />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice work! I still think you could solve it with z-index only, (check my updated answer again) but maybe it's cleaner this way.

Comment: You are right up to some point, the boxes do appear, however when clicked, the whole selected area turns white and the text is unreadable, which I can't stand. It's because of the parent-child rule, I guess.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what you mean. On my last answer when I click on the box, the area turns white and the text turns purple, so it stays perfectly readable. You don't get that?

Comment: No I didn't get that unfortunately :( Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Ok that's strange, I added the screenshot in my answer.